# Accessing values of a JSF managed bean in another managed bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a report generation page where I have few filters like `countryId`, `Date` and few other parameters for the user to select. Now based on the chosen parameters, there is a database call which uses these parameters to fetch a result list .

Now the managed  bean contains all these search parameters and the result list .Let us name this bean as `Bean1`

```
public class Bean1 implements Constants{
    private List<SelectItem> countryList;
    private List<String> choosenCountryList;
    private List<String> choosenProgramList;
    private String invoiceDatePriorTo= CalendarUtilities.getTodaysDate() ;
    private List<CustomResults> searchResultList
}
```

We have one more managed bean `Bean2` which contains a property of `Bean1`

```
public class Bean2 implements Constants {
    private Bean1 bean1;

    public getSearchResults(){
        //Code for fetching the search list for bean 1
        this.setsearchResultList() //=fetched list from DB;
    }

    public modifySearchResults(){}
}
```

Now when on the trigger of an action from the JSF page we call the `getSearchResults()` method and we set the `searchResultList` to be displayed in the screen .In this way we are able to display the search list on screen

Now the list we get is subjected to user modification on screen .Now when we again call the modifySearchResults to edit the list we are not able to retrieve the list in the bean2 because the managed bean is in request scope .

Can anyone tell me how to go ahead and solve this problem?

Answer (score 11):

Just declare your dataBean as `ManagedProperty`.

From the tagging I assume it's about JSF2.0.

You need to declare `bean1` as managed property in `bean2`.

It should look like

```
@ManagedBean
public class Bean1{
}
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
public class Bean2{

  @ManagedProperty(value="#{bean1}") 
  Bean1 bean1;
  //setter & getter of bean1

}
```

**See Also**

- [A nice article with example](https://maxkatz.org/2009/08/17/learning-jsf2-managed-beans/)

Comment: can u elaborate bit on what you want me to do ??

Comment: Jigar Thnx for your replies but I am already added that in facesconfig.xml

Comment: <managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>bean1</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.bean.Bean1</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>
 <managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>bean2</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.action.Bean2</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
   <property-name>bean1</property-name>
   <property-class>com.bean.Bean1</property-class>
   <value>#{bean1}</value>
  </managed-property>
 </managed-bean>

Comment: I don't see setter/getter in your bean

Answer (score 4):

Well you said it yourself. You have to move the bean from the `RequestScope`.

Depending of your application you may want to use:

- `@SessionScoped`
- `@ViewScoped`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/) you can find an article about choosing the right scope.

Second of all you may want to use Dependency Injection. JSF has the nice `@ManagedProperty`. You can read more about it [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/injecting-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/).

**EDIT**

Seeing now that you don't want to use the Session another solution which comes to my mind is the following:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean1 implements Constants{
    private List<SelectItem> countryList;
    private List<String> choosenCountryList;
    private List<String> choosenProgramList;
    private String invoiceDatePriorTo= CalendarUtilities.getTodaysDate() ;
    private List<CustomResults> searchResultList

    public getSearchResults(){
        // Your code here
    }

    public modifySearchResults(){
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

As you said the problem is that you can't save all the information from one request to the next. Usually this is a case when normally the `@ApplicationScoped` or `@ViewScoped` is used. For different reasons this may not be the best solution in some cases.

For your example placing all the methods in one bean which is `@ViewScoped` may be the best solution. This approach comes with its drawbacks but I think this is as good as it gets..

[Here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html) you can read more about this matter.

Comment: I don't want to use session scope ..is there any other way to do that .

Comment: @Sam Well I think you can approach this in a different way. Place the `getSearchResults()` in `Bean1` and annotate this bean with `@ViewScoped`. This way you will be able to have access to all information as long as you don't change the view.

Answer (score 1):

According to this page: [Accessing one managed bean from another](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MYFACES/Accessing+one+managed+bean+from+another)

How can I access one Managed Bean from another?

There are two ways for one managed bean to access another managed bean in the same web app:

Using dependency injection

Using JSF 2 `@ManagedProperty` annotation:

In your managed bean add a `@ManagedProperty` annotation to the related property and don't forget to add getter and setter methods.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "usingBean")
@RequestScoped
public class UsingBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{neededBean}")
    private NeededBean neededBean;

    public NeededBean getNeededBean() {
        return neededBean;
    }

    public void setNeededBean(NeededBean neededBean) {
        this.neededBean = neededBean;
    } // .... }
```

Binding through `faces-config.xml`: in your project's faces configuration file which defines the managed beans, a managed bean property can be declared as initialised with a reference to another managed bean:

```
<managed-bean> 
    <managed-bean-name>neededBean</managed-bean-name> 
    <managed-bean-class>fqn.to.NeededBean</managed-bean-class> 
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope> 
</managed-bean> 
<managed-bean> 
    <managed-bean-name>usingBean</managed-bean-name> 
    <managed-bean-class>fqn.to.UsingBean</managed-bean-class> 
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope> 
    <managed-property> 
        <property-name>neededBean</property-name> 
        <value>#{neededBean}</value> 
    </managed-property> 
</managed-bean>
```

The constraints are that:

- the using bean must have scope which is the same as or shorter than the needed bean
- the using bean must have a property-setter method which takes the needed bean as a parameter
- the beans cannot have managed dependencies on each other

**Using Lookup**

The following java code can be used in MyFaces 1.1 to explicitly look up an arbitrary managed bean by name:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
NeededBean neededBean = (NeededBean) facesContext.getApplication()
.getVariableResolver().resolveVariable(facesContext, "neededBean");
```

In MyFaces 1.2, that code is deprecated, and preferred version is:

```
ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(); 
NeededBean neededBean = (NeededBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication() 
.getELResolver().getValue(elContext, null, "neededBean");
```

Alternately, you can use this code to evaluate any JSF EL expression.

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
NeededBean neededBean = (NeededBean)facesContext.getApplication() 
.createValueBinding("#{neededBean}").getValue(facesContext);
```

Answer (score -1):

Best and well explained solution https://myfaces.apache.org/wiki/core/user-guide/jsf-and-myfaces-howtos/backend/accessing-one-managed-bean-from-another.html

Comment: This link is broken. That is why it is not recommended to answer questions with just links.